# Java OutOfMemory issue while transferring byte array

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, awt

I am writing remote desktop application. So I am transferring Images from one machine to another machine as byte array through socket. After receiving byte array I convert it into image and draw on a panel. Code looks approximately like below

```
imageBytes = //read from socket.
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bufferedImage.getSource());
Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(rmdPanel.getWidth(),rmdPanel.getHeight() ,Image.SCALE_FAST);
Graphics graphics = rmdPanel.getGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, rmdPanel.getWidth(),rmdPanel.getHeight(),rmdPanel);
```

I also store *imagebytes* till next image comes(for comparison). Now I am getting java out of memory exception in this code(while receiving byte array). I have heap size of 128 mb-512 mb. Image bytes sent are maximum 3mb.

Comment: Can you post the code that reads the byte array from the socket? You said the exception occurs while receiving the byte array, so that's probably where the problematic code is.

Comment: Nothing stands out from the code you pasted. Are you closing your streams? What do you mean when you say you run with 128mb-512mb? What are your Xms Xmx values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(you don't show the communication code, so i'm just guessing)  if you are using ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream over the socket streams, you need to be aware that they cache objects sent over the wire (to avoid resending the same data).  sometimes, this is a nice feature, but it can cause problems if objects are held too long.  you need to periodically call reset() on the ObjectOutputStream to clear this cache (in your case, possibly after every image send).

of course, the surest way to solve this problem is to attach a memory profiler and see what's using all the memory (or analyze a heap dump).

Comment: the jdk has a simple memory profiler in it (jhat) which will examine a heap dump (you can get your program to generate a heap dump when you get an OOM by adding the command line option -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError).  you can use jvisualvm (also in the jdk) to profile the app.  i believe netbeans and various other free ides include profilers.  or, you can buy one.  we personally use yourkit java profiler, which is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

```
imageBytes = //read from socket.
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Why read the image bytes into an array? You don't need that. It is costing you at least one extra copy of the data, maybe two if the ByteArrayInputStream copies the byte array. Just do ImageIO.read() straight from the socket.

Comment: No I need it because, if the image has not changed very much, i'll send only changed bytes and reconstruct at server side using previous image.This way i'll reduce network traffic.

Comment: @hnm: My point remains: you can use ImageIO.read() directly on the socket if the entire image is being shipped. If it isn't you can't use any of the code you showed. You can't 'send only the changed bytes' and expect ImageIO.read() to read them.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* ImageIO.read(...) does some sort of caching of images or their input streams so that may be causing you to run out of memory as you keep reading images.